# I am having troubles testing the module on file and on directory in python

Tags: python

I have been working on this question for 2 days. Here is what I have.  I am still getting the run checks to not go. Can anyone assist me?

Here is the question:

Write a recursive function, displayFiles, that expects a pathname as an argument. The path name can be either the name of a file or the name of a directory. If the pathname refers to a file, its filepath is displayed, followed by its contents, like so:

File name: file_path
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit...

Otherwise, if the pathname refers to a directory, the function is applied to each name in the directory, like so:

Directory name: directory_path
File name: file_path1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
File name: file_path2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
...
Test this function in a new program.

```
    import os
def print_file(file_name):
   with open(file_name, "r") as ifl:
       for data_line in ifl:
           print(data_line)

def myFind(input_path, z):
   spac = ''
   for i in range(z):
       spac = spac + ' '
       if (os.path.isdir(input_path)):
           for contents in os.listdir(input_path):
               new_content = os.path.join(input_path, contents)
               print(spac + new_content)
               if (os.path.isdir(new_content)):
                   myFind(new_content,z+1)
               else:
                   print(spac + input_path)
                   print_file(input_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
def print_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r") as ifl:
       for data_line in ifl:
           print(data_line)

def myFind(input_path, z):
   spac = ''
   for i in range(z):
       spac = spac + ' '
       if (os.path.isdir(input_path)):
           for contents in os.listdir(input_path):
               new_content = os.path.join(input_path, contents)
               print(spac + new_content)
               if (os.path.isdir(new_content)):
                   myFind(new_content,z+1)
               else:
               #    print(spac + input_path)
                   print_file(new_content)
```

You are calling print_file with the name of the folder instead of the name of the file you wish to open

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
def displayFiles(pathname):
    try:
        if (os.path.isdir(pathname)):#checks if it is directory
            for content in os.listdir(pathname):#traverses all the files in the directory
                displayFiles(os.path.join(pathname, content))#calls recursively for the files in the directory
        else:  
            print("Directory name:",pathname)
            print("File name:",os.path.dirname(pathname)+"//"+os.path.basename(pathname))# double slash for this assignment requires hard code
            fname=pathname
            file = os.path.basename(fname)#returns only the filename
            with open(fname, "r") as contents:
                for lines in contents:
                    print(lines,end='')#prints the contents
    except AssertionError as msg:
        print(msg)
```

Comment: Well it will be helpful for the questioner, if you explain your answer as well.

Comment: comments added, It gives all 5 out of 5 checks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).